# App status stuck in "Initial scan" for over a month

Tags: office-store

We've submitted office365 app to appsource and it haven't moved passed "initial scan". Our account has been approved, however the app itself made no progress.

We submitted it 07/03/2018 (mm/dd/yyyy).

When can we expect it to be reviewed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please open a support ticket [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=272975). Select App submission and validation in the first drop down and App Validation Status in the second. Our support team will then be able to look into this for you.